# Can user request's "Referer" be modified just in server side?

Tags: http, referer

I have a web site server which do such work like this:

The server receives request from user A(request referer is blank) and then redirect(at server side) user A to visiting web site B;

Is there any way I could modify user A's request referer to my domain name, then site B can get my domain name from user A's request?

Thanks in advance!

---

Because the web site B (my customer) want to know how many visits I have brought to him; I don't want to modify my client software and want to know if there's another can get this :)

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Because the web site B (my customer) want to know how many visits I have brought to him; I don't want to modify my client software and want to know if there's another can get this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the browser automatically sets the referrer unless the user disabled that behaviour. So: no, you can't change it server-side.

> Because the web site B (my customer) want to know how many visits I have brought to him; I don't want to modify my client software and want to know if there's another can get this :)

You could append a unique identifier to the URL so that your customer can track who is coming from your site:

http://www.yourcustomer.com/page.html?ref=bluesea007

Actually, [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) makes use of this principle.

Answer (score 1):

No, a redirect is just telling the client to use a different URL to complete the request. But the actual request to the new URL is done by the client, not the server. And the *Referer* header field is only set when the client followed an URL on a non-HTTP way (link click, form submission, “meta redirect”, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Only via a client-side (e.g. JavaScript) redirect as far as I know.  The kind of thing you just have to try it and see.